# Meaning of ど in 碧羅の天へ誘えど?

Tags: particles, song

It's been years, and I still don't know what the ど in this song title means.

It doesn't seem like it's 度｛ど｝, and I've tried looking up ど as a suffix many times before but the most I've come up with is that it might mean "place"?

So maybe 碧羅｛へきら｝の天｛そら｝へ誘｛いざな｝えど means "Where I get invited to Hekira no Sora (whatever that means)"?

If anyone has anything thoughts I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Does this help? https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7938

Comment: @OtheJared looks like "N0" means "[not taught anywhere, but commonly used](https://jn1et.com/jlpt-n0/)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ど is the same ど that shows up in the everyday word けど ("but").

This is a very old element of the language that first appears in the [*Kojiki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kojiki) of 712, all the way back at the beginning of written Japanese.  ど attaches to the 已然形【いぜんけい】 or "realis form", in modern Japanese more commonly talked about as the 仮定形【かていけい】 or "hypothetical form", the verb stem ending in -*e* for many verbs.  This ど is used to indicate a shift in sense to introduce a contrary proposition, much like the English terms "but", "however", "although", and the like.  This still appears in modern Japanese, but most often in formal or poetic contexts, and commonly with the emphatic inclusive particle も added afterwards.

- ...とは言**えども** -- formal, stiff, archaic contexts, seldom used in speaking
- ...とは言**っても** -- informal, regular, everyday contexts, used in speaking

If you can read Japanese, [the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 entry at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A9-579193) has a good description.